# Custom domain does not work in aws with serverless-next.js?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, next.js, serverless-framework

I am facing the same issue as [Github issue](https://github.com/danielcondemarin/serverless-next.js/issues/251) but for a different use case. I am trying to add multiple instances of the application: [Example code here](https://github.com/danielcondemarin/serverless-next.js/tree/a814869d9a1fc1462f5ea94c63a80a22eec0c609/packages/serverless-nextjs-component/examples).

With the domain added I am getting the same error:

```
Domain www.app.com was not found in your AWS account.
```

So to achieve the multiple instances, I tried a hack changing the env-prod file to `bucket="prod-appname"`. This gets deployed, but when I add an env-stage file to `bucket="stage-appname"`, this creates a new bucket, but deploys it to the same CloudFront URL. Is there a way to fix any of them so that I can achieve multiple instances?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

nextjsapp:
component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@1.18.0"
inputs:
bucketName: < S3 bucket name >

use this in servereless.yml and s3 bucket should be created in us-esat-1 (N.virginia)

and then deploy then a cloud front is created where the bucket is your s3 bucket after note the ID of cloud front and change the serverless.yml as

nextjsapp:
component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@1.18.0"
inputs:
bucketName: < S3 bucket name >
cloudfront:
distributionId: